# Google login / Fetch data after successful login

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I have added Google third party authentication to my web application. The google login works fine and I'm logged in successful. What I want to do is after the login into google to fetch the user data. Here is my function responsible for the login. 
`

```
/*Function which runs the google login feature*/
        $scope.onGoogleLogin  = function () {
            var myParams = {
                'clientid' : '******.apps.googleusercontent.com', //Client ID
                'cookiepolicy' : 'single_host_origin',
                'callback' : function (result) {
                    if(result['status']['signed_in']) {
                        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get(
                            {
                                "userId": 'me'
                            }
                        );
                        request.execute(function (resp) {
                            $scope.$apply(function () {
                                    $scope.username = resp.displayName;
                                    $scope.email = resp.emails[0].value;
                            })
                        });
                    }
                }, //callback function
                'approvalprompt':'force',
                'scope' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'
            };
            gapi.auth.signIn(myParams);
            $scope.isGoogleLoginWorking = true;
        };
```

`

I'm getting an error on this line.

```
var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get
```

Here is the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'people' of undefined

Comment: What do you see if you add `console.log(gapi.client.plus);` just above that?

Comment: It's working fine with adding gapi.client.plus. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I only asked you to do that because the error you showed was trying to read `.people` from something that was undefined, i.e. `gapi.client.plus`. Doing a `console.log` on that shouldn't change anything! If you changed anything else, could you make an "answer" with that so future searchers will know what you did?

Comment: Yeah no problem, I induced the line  gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function () after the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

```
`*/Function which runs the google login feature*/
        $scope.onGoogleLogin  = function () {
            var myParams = {
                'clientid' : '******.apps.googleusercontent.com', //Client ID
                'cookiepolicy' : 'single_host_origin',
                'callback' : function (result) {
                    if (result['status']['signed_in']) {
                       gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function () { //This solved the problem 
                            var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                                'userId': 'me',
                            });
                            request.execute(function (resp) {
                                $scope.$apply(function () {
                                    var username = resp.displayName;
                                    $scope.signUpModel.UserEmail = resp.emails[0].value;
                                    $scope.isGoogleLoginWorking = true;
                                    $scope.stringSplitter(username);
                                    $scope.submitCreatedUsersSocial();
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }, //callback function
                'approvalprompt':'force',
                'scope' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'
            };
            gapi.auth.signIn(myParams);
            $scope.isGoogleLoginWorking = true;
        };`
```